# Matlab: K-means clustering with predefined populations

Tags: matlab, statistics, machine-learning, k-means

I am trying to differentiate two populations.  Each population is an NxM matrix in which N is fixed between the two and M is variable in length (N=column specific attributes of each run, M=run number). I have looked at PCA and K-means for differentiating the two, but I was curious of the best practice.

To my knowledge, in K-means, there is no initial 'calibration' in which the clusters are chosen such that known bimodal populations can be differentiated.  It simply minimizes the distance and assigns the data to an arbitrary number of populations.  I would like to tell the clustering algorithm that I want the best fit in which the two populations are separated.  I can then use the fit I get from the initial clustering on future datasets.  Any help, example code, or reading material would be appreciated.

-R

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the data. But just to let you know K-means does get stuck at local minima so if you wanna use it try running it from different random starting points. PCA's might also be useful how ever like any other spectral clustering method you have much less control over the clustering procedure. I recommend that you cluster the data using k-means with multiple random starting points and c how it works then you can predict and *learn* for each the new samples with K-NN (I don't know if it is useful for your case).

Check [Lazy learners](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_learning) and [K-NN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm) for prediction.

Answer (score 0):

K-means and PCA are typically used in *unsupervised learning* problems, i.e. problems where you have a single batch of data and want to find some easier way to describe it.  In principle, you could run K-means (with K=2) on your data, and then evaluate the degree to which your two classes of data match up with the data clusters found by this algorithm (note: you may want multiple starts).

It sounds to like you have a *supervised learning* problem: you have a training data set which has already been partitioned into two classes.  In this case k-nearest neighbors (as mentioned by @amas) is probably the approach most like k-means; however Support Vector Machines can also be an attractive approach.

I frequently refer to *The Elements of Statistical Learning: Data Mining, Inference, and Prediction, Second Edition (Springer Series in Statistics)*  by  Trevor Hastie (Author), Robert Tibshirani (Author), Jerome Friedman (Author).